# Vertical animated css ul li menu

Tags: html, css

I wanted to create a CSS menu on my website that **animates to the right** when hovered.
I can create the design myself, but I don't know how to move it.

This is a demo of the effect: http://www.flashmo.com/preview/flashmo_207_vertical.

Comment: Just to make sure we're clear. You want to use CSS3 in order to do the animation on hover over a menu item (looks like a button of sorts), where the menu item will move slightly to the right while you are hovering, but move back when you are done?

Comment: another find [Cool Ol Li Design Using CSS3](http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/2014/03/cool-ol-li-design-using-css3.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming my comment is correct, this is how you accomplish that task.

with a working [JsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/FRMEc/)

HTML:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li>Menu Item 1</li>
    <li>Menu Item 2</li>    
    <li>Menu Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#menu li{
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: gray;
    color: lightgrey;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 5px;
    text-align: center; 
    transition-property:margin-left;
    transition-duration:1s;
    transition-timing-function:linear;

    /* Safari */
    -webkit-transition-property:margin-left;
    -webkit-transition-duration:1s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function:linear;

}

#menu li:hover{
    margin-left: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you able to use jQuery for your website?  That would be the easiest way to perform the animation you are looking for.  If you are restricted to using just CSS3 animations please see the answer provided by Charles380

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shaunp/sK5Nq/6/)

Example:

## jQuery

```
$('.bar').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).animate({"margin-left": "50"});
})

$('.bar').mouseout(function(){
    $(this).animate({"margin-left": "0"});
});
```

## CSS

```
.bar {
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
}
.bar {
    background-color: #000000;
    margin-left:0;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

## HTML

```
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>
```